# Python36 debug interpreter: from lxml import etree - ImportError: cannot import name eTree

Tags: python

once i tried to import etree from lxml from python_d.exe i got following output:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'etree'
```

But when i use regular python.exe (same version) this module imported successfully. This problem is not about only lxml module, but with some others (e.g. win32api). Do i have to run python_d with some specific flags or just these libraries can't work with debug python? I used Python3.6 on Windows 10, all libraries were successfully installed by pip

Comment: Any file or folder named `lxml.py` or `lxml` in your folder?

Comment: do that: `import lxml; print(lxml.__file__)` and get back to us.

Comment: Thx for reply! @klaus-d, i ran my python from `C:\Python36`, so there is no lxml.py or any other strange files. @jean-françois-fabre same reply for python & python_d - `C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\lxml\__init__.py`